# Sticky text in a table cell

Tags: css

I've got this basic table inside a wrapper
Let's say the wrapper is 1000px wide, and the table is 10000px wide.
The table has 100 columns, and the top row is 10 columns with a colspan of 10.

All this is made by angularjs and some `ng-repeat`

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr> <!-- Just 1 -->
            <td colspan="10"> <!-- Repeat for 10 -->
                <span>Some text</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <tr> <!-- Repeat for 7 -->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want the span with `some text` to stick to the edge of the container
`left: 0`

But it won't

Is it possible to make the content inside a td to stick?

Comment: It does...I'm not clear on what the issue is. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ZaNpdo

Comment: When scrolling, the td overflows to the left of the wrapper, but I want the span to be stick at the wrappers `left: 0`

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this?

```css
.wrapper {position:relative;}

.wrapper tr:first-child td {height:1.2em}

.wrapper tr:first-child span {position:fixed}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr> <!-- Just 1 -->
            <td colspan="10"> <!-- Repeat for 10 -->
                <span>Some text</span>
            </td>
            <td colspan="10"> <!-- Repeat for 10 -->
                <span>Some text</span>
            </td>
            <td colspan="10"> <!-- Repeat for 10 -->
                <span>Some text</span>
            </td>
            <td colspan="10"> <!-- Repeat for 10 -->
                <span>Some text</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <tr> <!-- Repeat for 7 -->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Repeat for 7 -->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Repeat for 7 -->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
            <td>content X</td> <!-- Repeat for 100-->
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The styles are really straightforward; the only trick I had to use was to give the top td elements a certain height, because otherwise they would collapse and the second row would appear in the same position as the first.

If this is NOT what you mean, please edit the question and clarify!